# How to schedule an operation to run at future time

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class TaskManager that holds a queue of tasks. Each time the next task is popped and executed.

```
class TaskManager
{
    TaskQueue m_queue;

    svc_tasks()
    {
         while (!m_queue.empty())
         {
             Task* task = m_queue.pop();
             task->execute();
         }
    }
};
```

Inside the Task there are certain points I would like to pause for at least SLEEP_TIME_MS milliseconds. During this pause I would like to start executing the next task. When the pause ends I would like to put the task in the queue again.

```
class Task
{
    int m_phase = -1;

    execute()
    {
        m_phase++;

        switch(m_phase)
        {
         case 0:
             ...
             do_pause(SLEEP_TIME_MS);
             return;
         case 1:
             ...
             break;
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a scheduler in std (C++ 17) or boost that I could use that would call a handler function when SLEEP_TIME_MS passes?

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `boost::asio::high_resolution_timer` with its `async_wait` method.

Every time when you want to schedule the operation of pushing task into queue you have to:

1. create `high_resolution_timer`
2. call `expires_after` which specifies the expiry time (SLEEP_TIME_MS) i.e. when handler is called. In your case in this handler you push a task into the queue.
3. call `async_wait` with your handler

---

If we assume that `execute` method returns `bool` which indicates whether a task is completed (all phases were executed), it may be rewritten into sth like this:

```
     while (!m_queue.empty()) // this condition should be changed
     {
         Task* task = m_queue.pop();
         bool finished = task->execute();
         if (!finished)
            scheduler works here - start async_wait with handler
     }
```

If I understand correctly, you want to push task into queue when `SLEEP_TIME_MS` is expired, so you cannot break loop when queue is empty, because you have to wait until pending tasks will be completion. You can introduce `stop` flag. And break loop on demand.

---

Below I put a snippet of code which works in the way you described (I hope):

```
struct Scheduler {
    Scheduler(boost::asio::io_context& io)
    : io(io) {}

    boost::asio::io_context& io;

    template<class F>
    void schedule (F&& handler) {
        auto timer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::high_resolution_timer>(io);
        timer->expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000)); // SLEEP_TIME_MS 
        timer->async_wait(
            [timer,handler](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
                handler();
            });
    }
};

struct Task  {
    int phase = -1;

    bool execute() {
        ++phase;
        std::cout << "phase: " << phase << std::endl;
        if (phase == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {

        }
        return true;
    }
};

struct TaskManager {
    Scheduler s;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Task>> tasks;
    std::mutex tasksMtx;
    std::atomic<bool> stop{false};

    TaskManager(boost::asio::io_context& io) : s(io) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            tasks.push(std::make_shared<Task>());
    }

    void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (stop)
                break;

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{tasksMtx};
                if (tasks.empty())
                    continue;
            }

            std::shared_ptr<Task> currTask = tasks.front();
            tasks.pop();

            bool finished = currTask->execute();
            if (!finished)
                s.schedule( [this, currTask](){ insertTaskToVector(std::move(currTask)); } );
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void insertTaskToVector(T&& t) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{tasksMtx};
        tasks.push(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::io_context::work work{io};
    std::thread th([&io](){ io.run();});
    TaskManager tm(io);
    tm.run();
```